# RHEL 7 Bash script not recognizing $args

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting, redhat

Below is my simple function to get user inputted file name, but for some reason my input validation isn't working.

```
function getname
{
        echo "Please enter the name of the file to install: "
        read filename
        if (($args > 1))
        then
                echo "You entered to many arguments."
                echo $USAGE
        exit
        fi
}

getname
```

**Bash -x test1** yields these results, as if it doesn't see any value for $args:

```
bash -x test1
+ getname
+ echo 'Please enter the name of the file to install: '
Please enter the name of the file to install:
+ read filename
testfile
+ ((  > 1 ))
test1: line 9: ((: > 1: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "> 1")
```

Why isn't this working?

Thanks!

Comment: Where do you assign content to the variable  $args?

Comment: Before the function definition I have an args=$#.. Maybe I'm going about this wrong, $# would return the command line arguments but I'm not passing any.

Comment: Your script works. That means the problem is in the part you didn't show here.

Comment: `$#` returns the _number_ of command line arguments, not the command line arguments. But according to the trace, the `args` variable is not set to anything. So no, you don't have a `args=$#` (That would've set `args` to a number: 0, 1, etc). It's absolutely not clear what you want to achieve -- if the user had entered multiple words, they will be all stored in the filename variable. For an example, try `read f; echo "{$f}"` and enter `foo bar`

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to ignore parts after spaces (awk, cut, sed could do the work), and even warning about such thing:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Input filename:"
read input
filename=$(echo $input | awk '{ print $1 }')
echo "Filename entered is: $filename"
[ "${filename}" != "${input}" ] && echo "(warning: parts after spaces were ignored)"
```

Also, using *read* conveniently, you could directly read what you want:

```
read filename garbage
```

You could consider convert spaces to underscores (or keep spaces as part of filename like windows guys ...):

```
read input
filename=$(echo $input | tr ' ' '_')
```

BRs